# Crystal Reports formula field not working when command field is zero

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a Crystal Report which has a command field

`count(service_ID)`:

```
select count(service_ID) 
from inbound_service 
where service_ID={?Service_ID}
```

and it is returning correct count values according to the database.

In the main report I have a formula field

`@Service_ID`:

```
if count(service_ID) =0 
then "ID Does not exists"
else {?Service_ID}
```

It is working if the command field is **not** equal to 0, but not working for `count(service_ID) = 0`.

If I try to show the command field value in a report, it is giving correct values for non-zero counts but showing nothing for 0 counts.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no rows in the DB that match {?Service_ID} then the result set from your SQL command will be empty and there will be no rows; it will NOT be the case that count(service_ID)=0. Instead you will have to use `isnull(count(service_ID))`

Edit: I overlooked the fact that you had a count() *in the SQL Command itself* and that the second "count" refers to that field and not a Crystal summary function. In this case, a single row with the value 0 should be returned.

Comment: :I tried doing as you said but it did not work, I did this 
 
`if isNull({Command.COUNT(SERVICE_ID)}) then "Does Not Exists" else {?Service_ID}`

it is showing does not exist even for matching value of service_ID if i browse the command field it is showing non zero value for matching service_ID but acting as null value in formula field and also if i try to show value of command field in report it is not displaying anything but on browsing its showing the count value.

Comment: @prash I made a mistake - see my edit. As for your problem, you may need to explain what else is in your report: What section are you placing this formula in? What does the rest of your data model and report look like?

Comment: i have many other fields in detail section but they are getting populated from another table and from main query of the report.
This formula field i am talking about is in report header section. There is no grouping done in the report.On browsing the command field it is showing expected value but when inserted in report header it is showing nothing. But if the main query returns some rows the inserted command field shows its value.

Comment: I inserted a null check for the command field in report header as @abc:`isNull({count(Service_ID)})` and it is showing **true** even if the browser value of `{count(Service_ID)}` is **1.00** but it should show **false**.

Comment: @prash I suspect part of your problem is how you're relating your SQL Command data back to your report's main query. If the inbound_service table is in your main query, maybe you could use Crystal's summary functions. If it's not in the main report, try a SQL Expression. A Command seems to me like overkill here and is giving you unpredictable behavior. your problem boils down to the first record in your main query not having a value in the Command but I can't say more as I don't know how they're tied together.